# Can we add an indicator on the flag dialog that the post is within the edit grace period?

Tags: feature-request, flags

Yesterday I flagged an answer as "not an answer". It was just a link. My flag was denied, and when I checked the post I realized I flagged it within the edit grace period and the OP had expanded the answer.

That was a bit stupid and rash of me, and I've wasted a moderator's time. Although obviously I should check the timestamp, I think some sort of indication that the post is within the edit grace period would be useful, something like:

[image]

And for bonus points, can we stop the textarea flowing out of the modal?

Chrome 16.0.912.75 m, on Win7, no zooming or anything weird...

Comment: +1. At the moment, I usually wait for the grace period to end, but having a reminder would be useful. Alternatively, a post that attracts flags could have its grace period revoked, so that the post as you flag it is pinned down in the revision history.

Comment: @lunboks Well I don't know about that. I usually post the simple quick answer, hit edit and start writing the proper answer. The grace period encourages that, and I don't think it's a problem. My compulsive flagging on the other hand is, I should have checked the timestamp, I'm mostly bringing this up because I've wasted someone else's time in the process.